# I can't see Extras Folder in Android Studio Folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have Android Studio installed and I want to run my app in my android device.

[In this part of the tutorial video](https://youtu.be/Qb2olFyoMV4?t=5m53s), I have to search for a Driver inside "extra" folder.

I'm not able to find this "extra" folder.

Android Studio is updated.

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download it first.

Open Google SDK Manager (or SDK Manager in Android Studio) and download "Google USB Driver"

[image]

**UPDATE**

As you described, you can't find any of the SDK folders. Since you already installed it, you are probably searching in wrong location. You can find proper SDK location in Android Studio. Try to search in the folder that you Android Studio is using as "Android SDK Location":

[image]

Comment: Are you able to find the "tools", "platform-tools", "build-tools" folder but only extra is missing?

Comment: i also can't see that

Comment: It means you are searching in wrong folder. I updated my answer. Could you please check it again